# I can't convert java code to xamarin android in below code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

When we set the tab an icon and text, you can see the icon is horizontally aligned with tab text. But if you want to place the icon above the tab label, you have to use a custom view to achieve it.

***Java***

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

***Xamarin.Android***

```
class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mFragmentList = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
    private List<string> mFragmentTitleList = new List<string>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager manager)
    {
        //base.OnCreate(manager);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mFragmentList.Count;
        }
    }
    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int postion)
    {
        return mFragmentList[postion];
    }

    public CharSequence GetPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position];
    }

    public void addFragment(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, string title)
    {
        mFragmentList.Add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.Add(title);
    }
}
```

1. What's that? when the super(manager) be covert to xamarin android.
2. CharSequence GetPageTitle. they got a error-> cannot  be used as return type

Comment: Calling a base constructor in C# like this `public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager manager) : base(manager) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mFragmentList = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
    private List<string> mFragmentTitleList = new List<string>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager manager)
        : base(manager)
    {

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mFragmentList.Count;
        }
    }
    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int postion)
    {
        return mFragmentList[postion];
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(mFragmentTitleList[position]);
    }

    public void AddFragment(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, string title)
    {
        mFragmentList.Add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.Add(title);
    }
}
```